# Convert String to Int and back to String

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert an email `String` to `Int32` then hash it using [HashidsNet](http://www.hashids.org/).

Finally, I revert the process to get the email again ... I tried the following:

```
HashidsNet.Hashids hash = new HashidsNet.Hashids();
String email = "john.smith@xyz.com";
Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(email);
Int32 number = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
String hashed = hash.Encrypt(number);
Int32[] numbers = hash.Decrypt(hashed);
Byte[] newBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(numbers[0]);
String newEmail = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newBytes);
```

Somehow `newEmail` becomes only `"john"`.

What am I missing?

Comment: `Int32` is 32 bit(4 bytes) as its name implies .

Comment: You are missing some `using` directives, my eyes!

Comment: Yes, I was testing my code without "using" ... Just corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert the first four bytes (`Int32` is a 32-bit type) to a number, encrypt, decrypt and decode them again. Four bytes in UTF-8 fit `john` quite nicely. You need an array of integers and in that case you can just as well use the `byte[]`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand ... Could you explain what should I change?

Comment: You tell BitConverter to use four bytes, starting at position 0 in the array and treat them as an Int32. Those happen to be the four bytes corresponding to `john`. Since you never put more data than that into the Encrypt method you cannot get more out either. Either convert `bytes` to an `int[]` of about a quarter of the length or simply use the array as is and convert straightforwardly to `int[]`, e.g. by using `hash.Encrypt(bytes.Cast<int>(x => x).ToArray())`.

Comment: I get the error Specified cast is not valid is not valid

Comment: Then `bytes.Select(Convert.ToInt32)`. Technically it's not my job to solve your problem, by the way and this is a fairly easy to solve error.